# Char literal differences?

Tags: c++, types, char

Been taking some STL c++11 courses and am hung-up on the specifications surrounding char literals.

Given the following char literals, I've been able to identify them as follows:

```
'a'   // unsigned char
L'a'  // wchar_t
"a"   // ??? char ?
L"a"  // ??? long wchar_t ?
```

The double quotation marks are the trip up, here.  As my lessons have not covered strings yet, the answer that is expected here is a form of char.

What type do `"a"` and `L"a"` represent ?

Comment: `'a'` is just a `char`, whether it is signed or unsigned is dependent on the compiler's implementation, the language standard doesn't dictate one way or the other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: also, regardless of it being signed or unsigned, `char` is always a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`, so there's no compliant platform where `typeid('a') == typeid(unsigned char)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lessons may have not covered strings yet, but nonetheless the values with the double quotation marks are string literals (the first narrow, the second wide); their types are respectively `const char[2]` and `const wchar_t[2]`.

Incidentally, many people often say that they are `const char *` and `const wchar_t *`, but it's incorrect - as all arrays they easily decay to a pointer to their first element, but they are arrays indeed, as you can check using e.g. `sizeof`.

Comment: Ah okay makes sense.  2 because of the null terminator ?

Comment: @RobertSmith yes

Comment: @RobertSmith: yes!

Comment: @RobertSmith Yes!!